# Matlab cannot import Python package (getting namespace module)

Tags: python, matlab, asammdf

I have a problem with this line in MATLAB:

`py.importlib.import_module('asammdf');`

It imports the library but it returns the following:

`'<module 'asammdf' (namespace)>'`

once I try to initialize MDF object (which is this lib part) with:

`MDF = py.asammdf.MDF();`

I will get the following error message:

`Unable to resolve the name py.asammdf.MDF`

Which by my understanding it means that the Python I use in MATLAB was able to track the 'asammdf' folder hence the namespace module, but it was not able to detect anything further.

I will note that I already tried the same approach on another machine and it worked fine. The imported module was returning:

`'<module 'asammdf' from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\asammdf\\__init__.py'>'`

and I was able to create MDF. It's strange because Paths are the same on boths computers.

I also already reinstalled Python with all libraries, still the same.

I think that it might be important - I can use this library outside MATLAB e.g. in python console.

All thoughts appreciated.